# Can C capture stdin/out to interact with other programs as if it were using a shell?

Tags: c, linux

I realise this is a strange question perhaps, but if say I have a program which can send commands to system like:

```
system(command);
```

The program can run and send commands to other programs via parameters like "ls -l".

However, if I have a program that requires interactive input e.g. make use of scanf, is there a straightforward approach to enabling my C program to effectively interact with it.

Apologies for the difficulty explaining my request. This is an exercise in a technical matter for reasons I can't concisely explain.

Comment: lol. No I swear on my children's children, this isn't for homework :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a straightforward approach to enabling my C program to
>   effectively interact with it.

Yes, you're probably looking for `popen(3)`. It lets you run a command and gives you a `FILE *` attached to its `stdin`/`stdout`.

Sadly, on Linux it's one-way: stdin *or* stdout, not both at the same time. At least one other implementation (FreeBSD) allows two-way pipes.

Comment: Hi, did you succeed in doing this? I tried with popen but it doesn't work. I open popen with "w" parameter. The program I try to open gets controlled with keyboard so I tried writing to it's input with fputc()

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would use the following pattern:

1. Use `pipe()` to open a pair of file descriptors that will be used as the stdin for your child process. (or `pipe2()` under linux)
2. Use `pipe()` to open a pair of file descriptors that will be used as the stdout for your child process.
3. Call `fork()`. You now have two processes, the parent and a new child process.
4. In the child process (ie. `fork() == 0`)

   1. use `dup2()` to create a new STDIN_FILENO and STDOUT_FILENO from the file descriptors created in step 1 and 2 above.
   2. use one of the `exec()` functions to start your new program.
5. In the parent process (ie. `fork() > 0`)

   1. close the unused sides of the pipes created in steps 1 and 2 above.
   2. detect child process terminating, using `waitpid()`
   3. close the remainder of the pipe file descriptors.

You can also capture stderr from your child process, by creating a 3rd pipe and `dup2()`ing it to STDERR_FILENO

`man pipe` has a snippet of code that shows how to use the pipes. And there are other [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4981113) of this pattern