# reading standard output via read function instead of fread

Tags: c++, c, linux, pipe

I would like my program to read the standard output produced by another application. I am aware that I can use `popen` to do that and use `fread` to read that output.

Do you know whether is possible to use `read` (and possibly `open`)? I am working in LINUX with C/C++

Comment: how about with your shell `$./program1 | ./program2`, this connects the stdout of progam1 to stdin of program2.

Comment: if you use pipe you don't need open, just read(pipe[], buffer, len)

Comment: And why don't you want to use `popen`?

Comment: @Jan. ..reading better my question, you are right.It is ok with using popen (also because I can give the caommand and args I want to run), but I do prefer using open instead of fread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a file descriptor for `read()` by calling `int fd = fileno(fp)` for the `FILE *fp` you have got from `popen()`. But be aware that you must not mix calling `read()` and `fread()`!

**EDIT**

If you want to avoid `popen()`, you have to use `pipe()`, `fork()`, `exec..()` and `dup2()` like it's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981113/dup2-and-exec)